# "Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should have required property 'karmaConfig' error on running "ng test" - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have been developing with angular with quite some time now but I have never ever written unit tests for any of my angular applications. I'm new to unit testing and was looking to get started with unit testing when I came across this issue.

With my angular application setup and based on the documentation I ran "ng test" to explore how the test works but I'm running in to the following error:
"

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should have required property 'karmaConfig'.
```

"
I'm unable to run anything or move forward because of this
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your project root directory, do you have a `karma.conf.js` file? Also, in your `angular.json` file, can you search for the `"karma.Config` property? It should be in the the `"test": {..., "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app had multiple configurations to integrate with depending on the environment so I just had to just run ng test with the following flag.

```
ng test --configuration=local
```